Is it possible to retrieve resource by another field than ID in Api Platform?
I want to fetch data from the API with the path /api/slug/{slug}. I tried with providers and controllers but always ended with this error:

Invalid identifier value or configuration

ID must be in IRI so I cannot change the identifier in ApiProperty.
Sample code:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Model\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Model\Parameter;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Model\Response;
use App\Controller\GetBySlug;
use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProductRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(),
        new Get(),
        new Get(
            uriTemplate: '/products/slug/{slug}',
            controller: GetBySlug::class,
            defaults: [
                'identifiedBy' => 'slug',
            ],
            read: false,
            openapi: new Operation(
                summary: 'Get product by slug',
                description: 'Get product by slug',
                responses: ['200' => new Response(description: 'OK')],

                parameters: [
                    new Parameter('slug', 'path', 'Slug of product', true),
                ]
            )
        ),
    ]
)]
class Product
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $content = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $slug = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(?string $content): static
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): static
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }
}

<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;

#[AsController]
class GetBySlug extends AbstractController
{
    public function __invoke(string $slug, EntityManagerInterface $em): Product
    {
        $product = $em->getRepository(Product::class)->findOneBy(["slug"=> $slug]);

        return $product;
    }
}


I can't find any useful information in the documentation or in GitHub issues.

While you may not be configuring a Subresource, there's a section on urivariables that should help you. Specifically, you will need to create a Link object to set up the mapping you need and load from your persistence layer via State Provider / Processor. A Controller could also work, but this is usually discouraged.

I'm using 2 GET operations with different uriTemplates: the first for editing with a granted role, the second for a public access with an invoke controller, but you need to return a JsonResponse
